# How to prevent a final cout in a loop from being executed?

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a code which gives the prime factorization of given integer.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void primefactor(int a);

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout<<" Enter the value of n "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    primefactor(n);
    return 0;
}

void primefactor(int a){
    while(a%2==0){
        cout<<"2*";
        a/=2;

    for(int i=3; i<=sqrt(a); i+=2){
        while(a%i==0){
            cout<<i<<"*";
            a=a/i;
        }
    }
    if(a>2){
        cout<<a<<endl;
    }

}
```

however when i run the output at the last factor i am getting an additional * in factorization. How can I remove this?

Comment: You know about `if` do you? Also your question title doesn't have anything to do with your actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
if (a != 2)
    cout<<"2*";
else
    cout<<"2";
```

instead of `cout<<"2*";`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it with a **goto** statement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

void primeFactorization(int number) {

cout << number << ": ";

// WHILE number is even
while (number % 2 == 0) {
   // SET number = number / 2
    number = number / 2;
   // PRINT 2
    cout << 2 << " " ;
    // END WHILE
}
//  GOTO TERMINAL
reloop:
// FOR factor in 3 to the sqrt(number), by 2
for (int factor = 3; factor <= sqrt(number); factor = factor + 2) {
    // IF number modular factor equals 0 THEN
    if (number % factor == 0) {
    // PRINT factor
        cout << factor << " " ;
    // SET number = number / factor
        number = number / factor;
    // GOTO INITIAL 
        goto reloop;
    // END IF
    }
    // END FOR
}
//IF number > 2 THEN
if (number > 2) {
    //PRINT number
    cout << number;
    //END IF
}
cout << endl;
}

int main() {

int usersNumber;
bool userWants2Play = true;

while (userWants2Play) {
    
cout << "Please enter a number to be factored: " ;
cin >> usersNumber;

primeFactorization(usersNumber);
 
    cout << "Do you want to play again? 1 or 0: " ;
    cin >> userWants2Play;
}

return 0;
}
```

The **goto** statement allows for the new odd number to go through the loop again. This lets the odd prime factors print and allows the new old number to be factored again, if the factor exists.